# failed building wheel for psycopg2

Tags: python, psycopg2, python-3.9

I need to download the package psycopg2 in order to work with the postgresql database in use. Unfortunately, when I try to `pip install psycopg2` the following error pops up:

> failed building wheel for psycopg2

my os: windows

---

log

```html
Building wheel for psycopg2-binary (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\Windows 10\.virtualenvs\project-e1HiiE3H\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Windows 10\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-u7m2a_o9\\psycopg2-binary\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Windows 10\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-u7m2a_o9\\psycopg2-binary\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\Windows 10\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-bv5plcfw'
       cwd: C:\Users\Windows 10\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-u7m2a_o9\psycopg2-binary\
  Complete output (24 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psycopg2
  copying lib\compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psycopg2
  copying lib\errorcodes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psycopg2
  copying lib\errors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psycopg2
  copying lib\extensions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psycopg2
  copying lib\extras.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psycopg2
  copying lib\pool.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psycopg2
  copying lib\sql.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psycopg2
  copying lib\tz.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psycopg2
  copying lib\_ipaddress.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psycopg2
  copying lib\_json.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psycopg2
  copying lib\_lru_cache.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psycopg2
  copying lib\_range.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psycopg2
  copying lib\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psycopg2
  warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

  running build_ext
  building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution no 1 (no need for compilation):

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
```

Solution no 2:

- get a C compiler
- `pip install psycopg2`

Comment: i have already tried both solutions still having the same log

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue. I've detailed my problem on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65821330/error-failed-building-wheel-for-psycopg2-ubuntu-20-04-python-3-8-5-venv