# How to solve ERROR: Failed building wheel for psycopg2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, linux, psycopg2

I'm having issues **building wheel for psycopg2** thru `pip install -r requirements.txt`. I'm on ubuntu 20.04 + python 3.8.5 + venv.

This is my requirements.txt:

```
amqp==2.6.1
anyjson==0.3.3
asgiref==3.2.10
billiard==3.6.3.0
brotlipy==0.7.0
celery==4.4.7
celery-progress==0.0.12
certifi==2020.6.20
cffi==1.14.2
chardet==3.0.4
cryptography==3.1
Django==3.0.3
dj-database-url==0.5.0
django-celery-results==1.2.1
django-cors-headers==3.5.0
django-crispy-forms==1.9.2
django-heroku==0.3.1
django-rest-framework==0.1.0
django-templated-mail==1.1.1
djangorestframework==3.11.1
djoser==2.0.5
fake-useragent==0.1.11
future==0.18.2
gunicorn==20.0.4
httpie==2.2.0
idna==2.10
kombu==4.6.11
lxml==4.5.2
pika==1.1.0
psycopg2==2.8.5
pycparser==2.20
Pygments==2.7.0
pyOpenSSL==19.1.0
PySocks==1.7.1
python-dateutil==2.8.1
python-decouple==3.3
pytz==2020.1
requests==2.24.0
six==1.15.0
SQLAlchemy==1.3.19
sqlparse==0.3.1
urllib3==1.25.10
vine==1.3.0
whitenoise==5.2.0
```

This is the output when I `pip install -r requirements.txt`:

```
[...]
Collecting urllib3==1.25.10
  Using cached urllib3-1.25.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl (127 kB)
Collecting vine==1.3.0
  Using cached vine-1.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
Collecting whitenoise==5.2.0
  Using cached whitenoise-5.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=3.0 in ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from gunicorn==20.0.4->-r requirements.txt (line 24)) (44.0.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: psycopg2
  Building wheel for psycopg2 (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /home/pierre/Workspace/campground_scavanger/venv/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-1xr9yjk0/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-1xr9yjk0/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-b8g9assp
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-1xr9yjk0/psycopg2/
  Complete output (6 lines):
  usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
     or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
     or: setup.py --help-commands
     or: setup.py cmd --help
  
  error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for psycopg2
  Running setup.py clean for psycopg2
Failed to build psycopg2
Installing collected packages: vine, amqp, anyjson, asgiref, billiard, pycparser, cffi, brotlipy, kombu, pytz, celery, celery-progress, certifi, chardet, six, cryptography, sqlparse, Django, dj-database-url, django-celery-results, django-cors-headers, django-crispy-forms, whitenoise, psycopg2, django-heroku, djangorestframework, django-rest-framework, django-templated-mail, djoser, fake-useragent, future, gunicorn, idna, urllib3, requests, Pygments, httpie, lxml, pika, pyOpenSSL, PySocks, python-dateutil, python-decouple, SQLAlchemy
    Running setup.py install for psycopg2 ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/pierre/Workspace/campground_scavanger/venv/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-1xr9yjk0/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-1xr9yjk0/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-8dtfz_uf/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/pierre/Workspace/campground_scavanger/venv/include/site/python3.8/psycopg2
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-1xr9yjk0/psycopg2/
    Complete output (40 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/_ipaddress.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/_range.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/extensions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/_json.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/_lru_cache.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/errors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/sql.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/tz.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/errorcodes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/pool.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/extras.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    running build_ext
    building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120005 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/home/pierre/Workspace/campground_scavanger/venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/12/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
    In file included from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:28:
    ./psycopg/psycopg.h:36:10: fatal error: libpq-fe.h: No such file or directory
       36 | #include <libpq-fe.h>
          |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    
    It appears you are missing some prerequisite to build the package from source.
    
    You may install a binary package by installing 'psycopg2-binary' from PyPI.
    If you want to install psycopg2 from source, please install the packages
    required for the build and try again.
    
    For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
    <https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>).
    
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/pierre/Workspace/campground_scavanger/venv/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-1xr9yjk0/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-1xr9yjk0/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-8dtfz_uf/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/pierre/Workspace/campground_scavanger/venv/include/site/python3.8/psycopg2 Check the logs for full command output.
```

Googling the first error `error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'` led me to run `pip install wheel` in my venv. Successfully installed wheel-0.36.2. **Not sure if this is related whatsoever with my psycopg2 issue hereafter but I'm showing all the steps I'm doing**.

I then reran `pip install -r requirements.txt` and now only the psycopg2 issue shows up:

```
[...]
Requirement already satisfied: vine==1.3.0 in ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 43)) (1.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: whitenoise==5.2.0 in ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 44)) (5.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=3.0 in ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from gunicorn==20.0.4->-r requirements.txt (line 24)) (44.0.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: psycopg2
  Building wheel for psycopg2 (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /home/pierre/Workspace/campground_scavanger/venv/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-zxwqo979/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-zxwqo979/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-fknnvsn3
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-zxwqo979/psycopg2/
  Complete output (40 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/_ipaddress.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/_range.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/extensions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/_json.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/_lru_cache.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/errors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/sql.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/tz.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/errorcodes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/pool.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/extras.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  running build_ext
  building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120005 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/home/pierre/Workspace/campground_scavanger/venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/12/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
  In file included from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:28:
  ./psycopg/psycopg.h:36:10: fatal error: libpq-fe.h: No such file or directory
     36 | #include <libpq-fe.h>
        |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  
  It appears you are missing some prerequisite to build the package from source.
  
  You may install a binary package by installing 'psycopg2-binary' from PyPI.
  If you want to install psycopg2 from source, please install the packages
  required for the build and try again.
  
  For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
  <https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>).
  
  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for psycopg2
  Running setup.py clean for psycopg2
Failed to build psycopg2
Installing collected packages: psycopg2, django-heroku, djangorestframework, django-rest-framework, django-templated-mail, djoser, fake-useragent, future, gunicorn, urllib3, idna, requests, Pygments, httpie, lxml, pika, pyOpenSSL, PySocks, python-dateutil, python-decouple, SQLAlchemy
    Running setup.py install for psycopg2 ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/pierre/Workspace/campground_scavanger/venv/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-zxwqo979/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-zxwqo979/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-r4aij71q/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/pierre/Workspace/campground_scavanger/venv/include/site/python3.8/psycopg2
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-zxwqo979/psycopg2/
    Complete output (40 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/_ipaddress.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/_range.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/extensions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/_json.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/_lru_cache.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/errors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/sql.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/tz.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/errorcodes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/pool.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/extras.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    running build_ext
    building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120005 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/home/pierre/Workspace/campground_scavanger/venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/12/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
    In file included from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:28:
    ./psycopg/psycopg.h:36:10: fatal error: libpq-fe.h: No such file or directory
       36 | #include <libpq-fe.h>
          |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    
    It appears you are missing some prerequisite to build the package from source.
    
    You may install a binary package by installing 'psycopg2-binary' from PyPI.
    If you want to install psycopg2 from source, please install the packages
    required for the build and try again.
    
    For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
    <https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>).
    
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/pierre/Workspace/campground_scavanger/venv/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-zxwqo979/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-zxwqo979/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-r4aij71q/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/pierre/Workspace/campground_scavanger/venv/include/site/python3.8/psycopg2 Check the logs for full command output.
```

I replaced `psycopg2==2.8.5` by `psycopg2-binary==2.8.5` as per some other stackoverflow threads but the same issue remains during the `pip install -r requirements.txt` .

If I install manually psycopg2-binary in my venv it works fine:

```
(venv) pierre@thinkpad:~/Workspace/campground_scavanger$ pip install psycopg2-binary
Collecting psycopg2-binary
  Using cached psycopg2_binary-2.8.6-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (3.0 MB)
Installing collected packages: psycopg2-binary
Successfully installed psycopg2-binary-2.8.6
```

But then again if I comment out `psycopg2==2.8.5` (or `psycopg2-binary==2.8.5` and rerun `pip install -r requirements.txt`, I keep getting the same error message.

**I'm not quite sure why there is a `Building wheels for collected packages: psycopg2` even if psycopg2 is commented out in my requirements.txt.** Dependency with another package?

Comment: FWIW I'm not having the issue on my Mac... pip install works great.

Comment: hey OP, did you happen to fix this issue and remember the solution ?

Answer (score 48):

Instead **pip** command use:

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

then use:

```
pip install psycopg2
```

Answer (score 8):

On Ubuntu, do you can install `psycopg2-binary`

```sh
pip install psycopg2-binary
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you need to install libpq-dev according to this [Problems compiling and installing psycopg2](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/faq.html#problems-compiling-and-installing-psycopg2).
`pip install libpq-dev` should work or perhaps a specific version may be required. About psycopg2 being commented yet it being attempted to install by pip it may be a requirement of one of your other dependencies.

Comment: `libpq-dev` is a system package, it must be installed with the OS package installer (for example `apt`, `yum`, `zypper`, `dnf`, `pacman` etc)

Comment: @snakecharmerb I thought it works after seeing [this](https://pypi.org/project/libpq-dev/) on pypi, can you confirm? Please check the usage section where they use pip to install it.

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't seen that package before :-)  It might work, but the repo hasn't been updated since 2016, so I'm not certain.  To be honest if I was having the question-asker's error I would either install `libpq-dev` through the system package manager or install `psycopg2-binary` if it was just for local development.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/1331#issuecomment-890041965

This is what worked for me.
Using WSL 2 using Ubuntu-20.04.

Answer (score -1):

After installing the right psycopg2==2.8.5 version, also check if your database is spatial and the right setting is there in your settings.py file for example if you are using postgres, set your database engine connection to;

'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',